# Start vsftpd instances by systemd target

Tags: centos, centos7, systemd, vsftpd

Used:

```
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

# systemctl --version
systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN

# vsftpd -v
vsftpd: version 3.0.2
```

Two config files was created:

`/etc/vsftpd/other21.conf`

```
...
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
listen_port=21
...
```

`/etc/vsftpd/another20021.conf`

```
...
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
listen_port=20021
...
```

Also a default config file was left in place:

`/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

These systemd units was activated:

```
# systemctl enable vsftpd@other21.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/vsftpd.target.wants/vsftpd@other21.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd@.service.

# systemctl enable vsftpd@another20021.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/vsftpd.target.wants/vsftpd@another20021.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd@.service.

# systemctl enable vsftpd.target
```

And when executed:

```
# systemctl start vsftpd.target
```

Instance `vsftpd@another20021` runs normally.

But `vsftpd@other21` doesn't start.
Instead of this for some reason runs instance with `default` config (on port `21`, it doesn't allow `vsftpd@other21` to start).

```
# ps x|grep ftp
  608 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
27390 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/another20021.conf
```

Content of unit files and generator from vsftpd-3.0.2-21.el7.x86_64.rpm are untouched:

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Vsftpd ftp daemon
After=network.target
PartOf=vsftpd.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/%i.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=vsftpd.target
```

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.target`

```
[Unit]
Description=FTP daemon
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Vsftpd ftp daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/vsftpd-generator`

```
#!/bin/bash

confdir=/etc/vsftpd
unitdir=/usr/lib/systemd/system
targetdir=$1/vsftpd.target.wants

mkdir -p ${targetdir}

for f in $(ls -1 ${confdir}/*.conf | awk -F "." '{print $1}' | awk -F "/" '{print $4}')
do
  echo "Generating systemd units for $f"
  ln -s ${unitdir}/vsftpd\@.service ${targetdir}/vsftpd\@$f.service > /dev/null 2>&1
done

exit 0
```

Activated units:

```
# find /etc/systemd -name 'vsftpd*'
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vsftpd.target
/etc/systemd/system/vsftpd.target.wants
/etc/systemd/system/vsftpd.target.wants/vsftpd@another20021.service
/etc/systemd/system/vsftpd.target.wants/vsftpd@other21.service
```

Why `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` is triggered?

What should be changed in systemd unit files additionally to start `vsftpd@other21.service` by `vsftpd.target`?

Comment: What is the contents of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd@.service`

Comment: @DerfK it's not been changed, I updated question with content of all systemd files and `/etc/systemd` listing

Answer (score 0):

> Why /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf is triggered?

This happens because you did not stop the initial vsftpd.service that was created and launched when installing the package.
To stop and disable this service you need to run the following commands:

```
# systemctl stop vsftpd.service
```

and then

```
# systemctl disable vsftpd.service
```

After executing these commands, the original vsftpd will free the occupied port and configuration file. Then you can start your second server instance.

> What should be changed in systemd unit files additionally to start
> vsftpd@other21.service by vsftpd.target?

There's nothing else that needs to be changed there. Everything you have indicated is correct.

--->

PS: I see that the question was asked six years ago and is most likely no longer relevant. But maybe my answer will help someone else who, due to their carelessness, will encounter the same problem :)

---<

Comment: default state is already disabled:

`$ systemctl status vsftpd.service`
`loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)`

your prompted me to check also:

`$ systemctl status vsftpd@vsftpd.service`
`loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)`

and on a clean system:

`$ yum install vsftpd`
`$ systemctl status vsftpd@vsftpd.service`
`loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)`

turns out it was my mistake to turn on vsftpd@vsftpd, thanks for where to look

Comment: but if I try to:

`$ systemctl disable vsftpd@vsftpd.service`

the problem remains:

`$ systemctl status vsftpd@vsftpd.service`
`loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)`

Comment: explored further:

`vsftpd@vsftpd.service` is "activated" (without symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/vsftpd.target.wants`) after enabling `any_name_here@vsftpd.service`